# Suddenly Azure App Service is throwing error

Tags: azure

When i am making a get request to the table, it is throwing this error on the application side. However on the postman, I am not getting any such error.

Status: **Unable** to recreate.
[image]

On the top, May i know why the request time is 2.3secs? its a lot if we compare. I have turned on `Always on` in app setting.

Comment: Have you added logging on the server to see what the "Internal Server Error" is?

Comment: Nope there isn't. Now I unable to recreate the error.

Comment: However, it will be good if you could help with the load time? @AndrésNava-.NET